# Trying to never repeat numbers in laravel from DB call

Tags: php, sql, laravel, frameworks

I have a form being submitted to add items to a database. These items are for different people from different companies. When someone submits the form i would get the last number entered for that company and then increment it by 1. So if you are from PPT i would check the last number entered for PPT and add 1 and update the database. Problem is if 5 people press submit at the same time it will all generate the same number for them all.

I can't use the build in increment feature for the ID because different companies are on the same table so PPT might add an item now then another company(TTS) adds 10 items after. When i add a next PPT after the 10 TTS i would get the last PPT item added and increment by 1.

How can i fix this in laravel to always get a new number even when everyone hit submit at the same time.

See my insert code below:

```
$courier = $cour->where('company_name', $request->idlm)->first();
$latest = $newInvent->where('idlm', $request->idlm)
->orderBy('id', 'desc')
->latest()->first();
if ($latest == null) {
   $updatebl = 10000;
} else {
  $updatebl = intval($latest->house_number) + 1;
}
$newInvent->tracking_number = $request->test_num;
$newInvent->first_name = $request->first_name;
$newInvent->last_name = $request->last_name;
$newInvent->description = $request->description;
$newInvent->houseBTL_number = strval($updatebl);
$newInvent->save();
```

Comment: When you use auto increment primary key of the database itself, you don't have to make a function for this. The requests to the server ar never at the same time. The records will be inserted and the id's will be counted by the db itself. In laravel you can achieve it by using `$table->increments('id');`

Answer (score 0):

I think you pretty much have it sorted, but consider doing this:

First create and save your `$newInvent`, but without your number.

Next, run a query to count the number of items for that company with a smaller ID and use that as the number.

```
// create and save the new inventory item
$newInvent = new ...
$newInvent->first_name = ...
...
$newInvent->save();

// calculate the sequence ID for the item
$seqId = InventoryItem::where('company_name', 'Acme Inc')->where('id', '<', $newInvent->id)->count();
$newInvent->number = $seqId;
$newInvent->save();
```

Because you're using the SQL auto-increment IDs (guaranteed unique) you can ensure that the concurrency issues will be taken care of.

If you're deleting items from the InventoryItem table make suer you're using [Eloquent's soft deletes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting), and then change your count query to:

```
$seqId = InventoryItem::where('company_name', 'Acme Inc')->where('id', '<', $newInvent->id)->withTrashed()->count();
```

to count the deleted items.

Comment: (You can roll the `where`s together if you want, I left them unrolled for clarity)

Comment: This is great. Only problem i am having with this is what if an item is deleted from the table. The count would be thrown off that way and items will be added twice

Comment: If you're using soft deletes (you should!) you can add `->withTrashed()` to your query. I've updated the answer.